# A word for "Let's see if you and I have got the point for this ongoing conversation ..."

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend and I are talking about an idea (like a chemistry lesson).

After the conversation goes on for some minutes, I need to **check** that what I said and what my friend said are really deeply understood by ourselves up to now.

So I repeat something we recently said (maybe in form of a question), to get a confirmation or verification (if there is one) to ensure that we have understood each other.

Is there a word (specially a verb) for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research following my dear friends' suggestions, I found that **go over** can be a better choice here.

According to McMillan English Dictionary, ***go over*** means *to repeat a series of things, or to think about them again in order to understand them completely*.

> **e.g.** Tom went over his arguments to see if they were clear enough up to that point.

To shed more light on my friend's suggestion ***recap***, I shall add it does not necessarily guarantee an effort to make sure both sides in a conversation completely understood what has been said so far, though the main topics are reviewed one by one. If we "recap," we're indeed reviewing the main headings/topics we have covered.

Also, ***cross-check*** lends itself more comfortably to academic and/or statistical contexts where the "validity" of data or figures is of more importance to us.

Comment: I like it. Also, check [go over](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+over) and [going over](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/going-over). (The Free Dictionary)

Comment: I just read your post. *Go over* in "Tom went over his arguments...* doesn't fit in your context as it means to **examine** or **check**. Its objects could  be plans, schedules, arguments (prepared), homework, analysis, etc. Does your question have any of the objects that I mentioned? It doesn't fit in your context better than to recap unless you say "Let's go over what we have discussed". It is not a single word.

Answer (score 3):

The verb [**recap**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recap) is broadly used for such context and it means:

> State again as a summary; recapitulate:
>
> (with object) *a way of recapping the story so far*.
>
> (no object) *to recap, the committee has decided to ask Farris,
>   Cullen, and Jurgens to go*

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: thank you, but does that merely mean repeating of what has been said?

Comment: @vandaad Yes, the verb fits in the context you provided. To recap doesn't necessarily mean that you repeat what you said word by word. It has a sense of repeating as a summary, but in a less condensed sentence than to summarize.

Comment: Okay, By the way... Imagine we are speaking... by saying "let's recap", I want myself and you to check what we said by repeating the main points.right?

Comment: @vandaad Yes. "Let's recap" is broadly used for that purpose.

Comment: I did some more research on this and came up with yet another verb that, to me, sounds more like what I've been looking for. Please check my own answer to this question. Again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use ***cross-verify*** or ***cross-check***

**[cross-check](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%E2%80%93check)**

> (verb) to check (as data or reports) from various angles or sources to determine validity or accuracy

[Merriam-Webster]

Although the definition says from "various sources", you can apply this to discussion as well.

**Usage:**
Let's **cross-check** (or cross-verify) our understanding on this topic